# Is there a specific name for square matrices of this form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to read more about linear algebra than my college class covered, and I was wondering if there was a specific name (other than diagonalizable) for square matrices of the form
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & a\\
0 & b & 0\\
c & 0 & d\\
\end{bmatrix}
\mbox{for}\space a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}, \mbox{where}\space a,b,c,d \ne 0 \space\mbox{and} \space d^{2} + 4ac \ne 0
$$
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  I got $\begin{bmatrix}1-\phi & 0 & 0\\ 0 & \phi & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. What next?

Comment: I was confused about that example. How do you know it's diagonalizable in general?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich My question is based off (and is not an exact copy) of a question on the final (which I took last Monday). The professor said to assume that all matrices of that form are diagonalizable. That assumption is one of the things I want to read more about.

Comment: It's not diagonalizable if $d^2+4ac=0$ and $d\ne0$

Comment: Interesting. Why exactly is that?